# in active admin i'm trying to send notification to all users in a single selection of all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, input, notifications, activeadmin

i want to select all in a single go(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBGmH.png)
this is my input form. in user_selection i want to send notification to all without selecting on by one[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBH9t.png)
this is my model for notification (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mic5Z.png)

i try lot of things like install activeadmine_addons, pass in a array